# Whisker Plot EXCEL Year and Month Data Table

Tags: excel, boxplot

This seems very straight-forward but impossible for me. I need a box/whisker plot in Excel using Windows 10 Enterprise using Insert "Box and Whisker" from the provided "All Charts" options. I cannot get the box and whiskers to appear - only "X" markers for each month as you can see below. I have selected A1:M31 to include a year column and the 12 month columns for a header row + 30 data rows. The final plot requires 12 box and whiskers (one for each month 1-12) and the 30 data points of yearly data for each month.
My data looks like this:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
1993    1844595.6   1518957.3   1817755.6   2147873.7   1860113.7   2000736.1   2007341.1   1458790.4   1500334.8   1775501.9   1952770.1   1912588.7
1994    2076654.3   1910081.1   1987075.1   2280485.8   1851344.2   1764834.0   1775928.6   1534043.2   1386870.4   1935983.9   2368630.3   1649125.5
1995    1821607.2   1760775.9   1905855.2   2118836.8   2095559.6   1659021.2   1657974.2   1382140.5   1373922.1   2014628.2   2031395.3   1822144.4
1996    2322967.1   2118366.0   2201040.4   2287578.1   2366169.3   1672723.1   1513473.8   1435926.9   1536152.9   2138206.6   1904328.4   2135288.3
1997    2342289.3   1856623.7   2316904.4   2013600.9   1994058.7   1727654.0   1617514.3   1357927.8   1400243.0   2014703.6   1728829.4   1894376.2
1998    1791230.4   1623505.0   2138280.0   1858687.7   2093629.0   2147048.9   1466174.3   1282609.3   1350791.3   1840035.5   1955246.9   2014138.4
1999    2308027.6   2096884.2   2155125.9   2336483.0   2239346.9   2020068.2   1743207.4   1501784.6   1428895.9   1693102.1   1697256.1   2061422.9
2000    2058209.6   1922571.2   2069637.1   2074980.4   2266043.8   2047017.4   1628606.7   1587146.3   1680971.8   1732530.4   1807045.9   1849322.3
2001    1868165.0   1783256.4   1917455.6   2347997.2   2035693.0   1774791.0   1627000.6   1479302.2   1380584.3   2084917.8   1800103.5   2024567.1
2002    2133033.7   1942941.8   2364714.1   2309962.9   2233205.6   1880701.8   1690921.3   1574168.7   1538342.3   1531407.3   1678639.7   1927892.5
2003    1679675.7   1856866.0   2072282.8   2148401.1   1938537.5   1662813.6   1641041.5   1288372.0   1539947.6   1650563.5   2061427.2   2101918.8
2004    1879085.9   1820774.7   2232957.4   1980205.1   2279085.6   1716446.5   1487098.2   1528418.4   1660822.7   1928467.2   1732668.3   1970480.2
2005    1778844.8   1447194.3   2032841.9   2131726.9   1986437.6   1936439.1   1628742.1   1366462.1   1571530.2   1603340.4   2058922.9   1755983.1
2006    2280409.8   1879340.9   2241970.3   2181210.3   1996013.3   1549954.2   1578430.9   1476722.9   1532157.5   1909699.4   1859739.4   1961891.2
2007    2080793.6   1858164.3   2283446.2   2200048.9   2069012.5   1843784.9   1490654.1   1396634.4   1681418.9   1882946.8   1764152.0   2041464.3
2008    2300715.2   2019087.7   2322596.8   2385377.2   2320109.8   2052935.3   1607381.0   1397802.0   1383763.3   1754961.4   1840667.1   2397390.8
2009    2180494.6   1993575.8   2386994.0   2390988.6   1989850.9   1798074.9   1620769.4   1680202.0   1338162.4   1985078.8   1705934.6   1855734.1
2010    1853718.5   1412644.5   2020000.7   2272340.0   2213994.5   1928714.3   1663170.6   1583837.0   1628422.4   1719980.4   2072792.8   1981306.2
2011    1846969.3   2243222.9   2169241.7   2648822.2   2461078.7   2151444.0   1574889.2   1545610.2   1360591.6   1848766.5   2261577.8   1848521.5
2012    2220215.1   1918906.4   2386107.7   2122777.5   2086670.4   1944370.2   1604351.8   1423456.2   1353821.0   1959926.1   1603586.3   2046112.6
2013    2066775.6   1970165.1   2138842.9   2396208.2   2187386.0   1827605.8   1644778.1   1329142.9   1617132.8   1742192.8   2058547.7   1967184.3
2014    2304963.5   1917137.8   2248475.7   2392909.5   2123264.7   2104969.5   1688914.0   1392053.1   1474222.6   1719260.8   2254969.0   1792244.0
2015    1756204.3   1738631.9   1736764.6   2021739.0   2075140.6   1549841.4   1674523.3   1555985.2   1470431.5   1789199.0   2085165.3   2133372.3
2016    1872136.2   1933395.1   2150673.9   2137902.4   1926153.8   1650678.1   1797306.4   1408405.4   1593267.1   1733120.8   1757140.8   2225601.8
2017    1907357.8   1945729.3   2274209.0   2198374.2   2018490.2   1819870.6   1572311.4   1405069.7   1502111.7   2039207.8   1900655.8   1812575.3
2018    2034806.2   2107391.0   2162906.3   2177490.0   1956376.6   1972625.9   1518084.4   1633873.6   1451033.0   1688823.3   1799107.4   1874133.6
2019    1878122.1   1750745.3   1958698.5   2188778.1   2101388.4   1858040.2   1706108.9   1545087.5   1725558.9   2042723.6   1733478.7   1792768.3
2020    2131324.7   2119275.1   2284755.1   2083093.1   2037678.8   2050670.1   1715393.7   1555679.8   1609174.7   1964063.7   2038570.7   1953007.1
2021    1803716.5   1993237.6   2324489.2   2159483.6   2026284.9   1630869.5   1524063.4   1590530.0   1566462.0   1803526.8   1895600.5   2212690.2
2022    1966988.7   2085787.1   2294692.2   2528719.3   2333948.9   1808702.3   1713001.1   1490707.6   1354659.9   1684464.7   2066711.0   2037830.2
```

My Excel box and whisker plot looks like this now:
thank you!

[image]

If I incrementally add the "Series Name" - e.g., 1,2,3...12 in the right click "Select Data" on the plot I do get 12 box plots but then the series names are not aligned with the month numbers as shown below. Right-click on x axis to "Format Axis" does not give an option for xtick marks.

[image]

Comment: Just to make sure - you want 30 boxes (one per year), not 12 (one for each month), right?

Comment: hi - No.  just like the above plot with 30 data points (years) for each month 1-12. So, there should be 12 box and whiskers, one for each month of the 30-year data.

Comment: Oh okay, then I assumed something wrong in my reply. The key trick is to only select the data then and you're good to go from there, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

### Getting the right style

The reason why the chart contained crosses is because you added the first column. Without the first column, the chart style should be fixed.

### Splitting data from labels

Since you have numeric labels immediately, they will get incorporated into your data if you select both upon chart creation. If however your series labels are text rather than numbers (e. g. Jan-Dec), then you *can* select data + labels and it will work out-of-the-box. I **strongly** recommend temporarily changing the labels to text (like Jan-Dec), then create the chart, and then replace the first row with 1-12 again *after* the chart has been created. This saves a lot of manual steps:

1. Change series names (first row) into some text
2. Select series labels + data (but not the first column remember)
3. Insert > Charts > Statistics > Box and Whisker; you should now have your 12 boxes
4. Change the labels back

If for whatever reason you cannot temporarily swap the labels, your only way is to make Excel start from only the data, and work your way up by adding the series names manually:

1. Only highlight the data
2. Insert the chart
3. Right click on the chart > "Select data..."
4. One by one, select each series, click "Edit", click on the series name from the first row, and hit "Enter"

### Adding the series names

To get the boxes be labeled 1-12, there are two options:

The "quick but maybe good enough" option is to add the legend in "Bottom" position. It will of course be styled as the legend and not properly aligned, but it should do the job of getting the information across.

If you want something fancier, you can have the series names appear right below (or above) the boxes.

1. While the chart is selected, in the contextual ribbon tab "Chart Design", from the "Add Chart Element > Axes" menu, deselect the "Primary Horizontal" axis, since it doesn't add any value to the chart.
2. Right click on the chart area and select "Format Chart Area" to bring up the formatting side panel.
3. Click on one of the boxes, which should select "Series Options" (the button with the bar chart icon).
4. Move the first slider "Gap Width" to 2% (from 330% on my machine). This will distribute the boxes over the full width of the chart rather than squeezing them all into the center.
5. Right click on the first series, and select "Add Data Labels". A bunch of numbers will appear to the right of the box.
6. Click on one of the labels, and in the formatting panel, select "Label Options" (bar chart icon again).
7. Check the "Series Name" checkbox for "Label Contains"; this should replace all numbers (the "Value") with the series name.
8. From the radio button group "Label Position" beneath, select "Below" (or "Above").
9. In the chart, click on any of the data labels; it will select all data labels. Click again on any label except the one you want to keep to only select a single label. Hit "Delete" on your keyboard to remove it. Tips: make sure that the second click is on the label area and not its border (your cursor should be the default one, not the movement arrows), and it has to be two single clicks, not a double click. Zoom in if you have a hard time hitting the labels.
10. Repeat step 9 for all data labels that you don't need.
11. Repeat step 5-10 for the other series.

[image: The chart after adding all series names below]

Comment: Doing what you suggest above gives me the correct 12 box plots but NO option to align the boxes with the month numbers 1-12.

Comment: Does it have to be on the axis? Because there is a way to get the "1-12" to appear above/below the boxes themselves in the chart. If you are fine with that, I can add the information for that, too.

Comment: I added the information on how to get the month numbers into the chart. Alas I don't know any way to get them on the x axis, but maybe my solution will do for you.